# Why are the arguments to a thunk wrapped inside of an object?

Tags: redux, thunk

I'm trying to understand thunks in redux:

```
const thunk = ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
  if (typeof action === 'function') {
    return action(dispatch);
  }
  return next(action);
};
```

And I'm having trouble understanding why the arguments are being passed as an object (or is it object deconstruction?). Why aren't they just being passed as `dispatch, getState`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux middleware are given a miniature version of the Redux store API as an argument to the outermost function.  The full store API is `{dispatch, subscribe, getState, replaceReducer}`.  Middleware are only given access to `{dispatch, getState}`.

As to why it's an object instead of separate arguments, [that's simply an implementation detail](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/45281b6b3f6bfe69ceb2450c2c48961e2891d2c9/src/applyMiddleware.js#L29-L34):

```js
    const middlewareAPI = {
      getState: store.getState,
      dispatch: (...args) => dispatch(...args)
    }
    const chain = middlewares.map(middleware => middleware(middlewareAPI))
    dispatch = compose(...chain)(store.dispatch)
```